# Switch disks between array controllers

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an [HP ProLiant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProLiant) ML 350 G5, which has an HP Smart Array E200i/128 BBWC Controller embedded. This controller manages two arrays (each with three 72 GB disks in [RAID 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_5))

This controller has problems.

I pretend to connect an HP Smart Array P800/512 BBWC.

Do I need to reinstall the OS, or there is a way to assign these six disks, in two arrays, in the new controller, without losing the information on them?

Answer (score 4):

The RAID metadata in HP Smart Array RAID array lives on the disks and not the controller. The Smart Array E200i and P800 are of the same generation and are entirely compatible with each other.

- Dont change the disk order.
- Obviously, you'll want to do this with the server powered off.
- You may need additional cabling to attach the disk backplane to the P800 controller.

Please make sure you update the firmware of the devices, as the P800 controller firmware offered additional features via firmware throughout its lifetime.

Comment: The warning that the system generate is:
Event Id  129 -  SOURCE= hpcisss2 - "Reset to device, \Device RaidPort0, was issued."
I have read so much about this event. The server (hardware and SO are update).  I decide to apply another array controller because I do not have problems with the disks (HP Insight Diagnostic Online does not reports errors on disks) The server SO is Windows 2008 server. 
Would I resolve this issue with the new array controller?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import the existing RAID containers to the new controller. Use the HP bootable RAID utility and read the manuals for both controllers so you don't inadvertently mangle your RAID sets.